# what is the minimum data size of a file to see the benefits of hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have done quite some research on this topic but am not yet satisfied with the answers that are found. Some say that it doesn't only depend on the size alone, there are many other factors that affect while others say that it needs to be in the size range of few TB's to see the true nature of hadoop. So, what is the minimum input data size to test hadoop functioning over a similar java programs?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it depends on different things. I would imagine it depends on at least the following:

- File size(s)
- Data type and format
- Cluster size and performance
- Network connections between clusters
- Types of calculations and analysis

In general, the more data you have and the more complex it is, the better Hadoop performs compared to "regular" Java programs. There are no certain limits that I can give you.

Definition from a "Hadoop buyer's guide" (Robert D. Schneider) small book for the term "Big Data" should give you also some guidance:

> Big data tends to describe one or more of the following characteristics
>
> - Encompasses large amounts of information
> - Consists of a variety of data types and formats
> - Generated by disparate sources
> - Retained for long periods
> - Utilized by new and innovative applications

Comment: I was working on 1GB file in hadoop and I was appalled with the results as simple Java was running much faster than hadoop with 4 nodes. I couldn't understand the reason behind the anamoly. Do you think 1GB file is too small to see the effects of hadoop?

Comment: It really depends. Often the term "Big Data" is associated with sizes of terabytes, not gigabytes. I wouldn't call 1GB big in any sense.

Comment: @Trinimon: Kindly look into the above issue